# Magento Tag Url Rewrite and Generate

Tags: magento

I added lots of rewrite rules for tags in Magento. For example,

```
Request Path: tag/abc
Target Path: tag/product/list/tagId/7/
Type: Custom
```

Everything is going well in the request and response. But I am wondering how to change the tag URL in the front? Although the rewrite rules run perfectly it will not change the URL which has been rewritten.

I found the `getTaggedProductsUrl()` method in tag module and eventually, like others, it calls `getUrl()` method in core/url Model. I tried to add, `'_use_rewrite' => true` to the route params. But it does not generate the right URL.

I really would like to know what's wrong about this!

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite the `tag/tag` model and override the `getTaggedProductsUrl()` with the following it will work:

```
public function getTaggedProductsUrl()
{
    $fullTargetPath = Mage::getUrl('tag/product/list', array(
        'tagId' => $this->getTagId(),
        '_nosid' => true
    ));
    $targetPath = substr($fullTargetPath, strlen(Mage::getBaseUrl()));
    $rewriteUrl = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->loadByIdPath($targetPath);
    if ($rewriteUrl->getId()) {
        return $rewriteUrl->getRequestPath();
    }
    return $fullTargetPath;
}
```

This is assuming you are using the target path without the base url as the "ID path" **and** the "Target Path" property, e.g `tag/product/list/tagId/30/`.
If you don't want to duplicate that setting then you will need to use the tag resource model and manually adjust the SQL to match the `target_path` column instead the `id_path`, because the resource model doesn't come with a method predefined for you.
Still, you can use the `Mage_Tag_Model_Resource_Tag::loadByRequestPath()`method as a reference.